# Excel Data Validation if condition is true, require value in proceeding cells

Tags: excel

I'm trying to figure out how I can make it so if cell A1 has a value then b1, c1 and d1 must all also have a value before proceeding to the next row.

Comment: The [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro can be used to expand [data-validation] to almost any extent.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the entries in that range. It would have to be zero or 4. DV in A1 with Allow = Custom and Formula =

```
=OR(COUNTA(A1:D1)=0,COUNTA(A1:D1)=4)
```